# Select only text without numbers in CSS li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How modify this existing CSS code to select only text instead copying along with numbers.

```
CSS

.snippet-wrap {position:relative; width:640px;}
.snippet-wrap li { text-shadow:none;}
.snippet-wrap .snippet-num {list-style:none;counter-reset:paragraph;}
.snippet-wrap .snippet-num li {color:#333;border-left:1px solid #BDC3C7;margin-left:22px;} 
.snippet-wrap .snippet-num li:before {color:#999;margin-left:-24px;margin-right:10px; counter-increment:paragraph;  content:counter(paragraph);
    display:inline-block; text-align:right; width:20px;}

HTML

<ol class="snippet-num">
<li><span>Vegetables</span></li> 
<li><span>Soya</span></li> 
<li><span>Wheat Grass</span></li> 
<li><span>Cheque</span></li> 
</ol>
```

Current

[image: Result]

Desired

[image: Desired]

Comment: This seems to be a browser-dependent issue, in FF [only text is selected](http://jsfiddle.net/wjtjfpo7/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `-webkit-user-select: none;`

to your `.snippet-wrap .snippet-num li:before` CSS such that:

```
.snippet-wrap .snippet-num li:before {
  -webkit-user-select: none;

  /* rest of your CSS properties */ 
  ....
}
```

read more about `user-select` to maintain browser compatibility:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select